# MySQL super slow query after 3 attempts

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord Level Bot, the bot will insert a random amount of XP each time a user's typed a message in the chat. To see a user's level I have a `!level` command. Like this :

```
      sql.query(`SELECT * FROM WMembers where DiscordID = ${message.author.id}`, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)

        if(!rows[0]) return message.channel.send("The user has no XP!")
        let xp = rows[0].XP
        let level = rows[0].Level
        let nextLevel = level * 40
      message.channel.send(**Level: **${level - 1}\n**Points: **${xp} / ${nextLevel}`)
      })
```

**However, when I call the command more than 2-3 times,the queries start executing extremely slowly, taking 5 minutes to finally return the value.**

Here is my sql code :

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host    : keys.dbHost,
    port    : 3306,
    user    : keys.dbUser,
    password: keys.dbPass,
    database: keys.dbName
});

let sql = {};
sql.query = function(query, params, callback) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) { 
      if (callback) callback(err, null, null); 
      return; 
    }

    connection.query(query, params, function(error, results, fields) {
      connection.release();
      if(error) { 
        if (callback) callback(error, null, null); 
        return; 
      }
      if (callback) callback(false, results, fields);
    });
  });
};
```

If someone can help me, I will greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: 1. Where is the database hosted?

2. What is the structure of that table

3. How many rows does the table currently have? 

4. Have you added the database index for the DiscordID yet?

Comment: The database is hosted on a small cheap VPS. There are only 3 rows and everything is properly setup (DiscordID, XP, etc columns). I was going to get a better VPS but I don't know if it will resolve the issue.

Comment: how much memory does your VPS have? is this some specific DB hosted on AWS or something?

Comment: No, it's specifically designed for Discord's bot, has 128MB RAM.

Comment: Try to set `max_connections = 1` in MySQL config and repeat test

Answer (score 1):

you clearly don't have enough memory for your database: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-monitor/4.0/en/system-prereqs-reference.html

MySQL's minimum requirements dictate 2GB of memory. you won't get far with 128MB. On that note, just like it has been adviced by @ExploitFate, limiting the number of connections your application can make to the database will also save you some memory

Comment: I used the same server for another bot but it doesn't have any delays, same server and the same RAM. I don't really know why it would work on my other bot.

Comment: are they connected in the same time to the same db and only one of them has issues?

try running the following mysql query when the slowness issue manifests again `SHOW STATUS WHERE \`variable_name\` = 'Threads_connected'` . This will show you how many connections are currently done to the db. Chances are that your connection either dies or your app just creates a crazy amount of connections

Comment: do you have SSH access to the machine running your DB? if so, is it a windows? linux?

Comment: The delay can be fixed by restarting the bot, all commands work perfectly after restart and the `Threads_Connected` is also showing `100-110` even though it's working perfectly until after 3 commands where it delays again.

Comment: here are the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-use.html
They contain all the data you need to calculate the exact amount of memory you need to manage 105 connections. But yeah. If you have 2 clients, then this number should be 2, not 105. I still believe you're running out of memory, but this might be dictated by how your clients connect to the server

Comment: in particular it's possible for a client to open more than 1 connection. Some frameworks immediately open 5 connections just to make sure that if one connection dies, you can always use another

Comment: if you're running the server on a linux machine, you can check out how much memory you have left: https://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/

if you for instance run the `free -m` and see that you're using the swap memory, this will prove my point (swap memory = using hard drive instead of RAM, because you're all out of RAM)

Comment: I got plenty of RAM left, I believe that it's definitely not a RAM issue.

Comment: you don't have much to begin with. You have 1/16th of the official minimum requirements, but if you don't trust the official documentation, then there's not much I can do for you. Either way, it looks like your client generates too many connections for no good reason